# Weakest theory equi-consistent to ZFC

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I've recently read that ZF is equi-consistent to ZFC. From what I understand, to establish this we transform a formal proof of a contradiction in ZFC into a formal proof of a contradiction in ZF.

We do this by constraining all quantifications to the [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) : $\forall x,\phi$ is replaced by $\forall x, \text{Constructible}(x)\Rightarrow \phi$ and $\exists x,\phi$ is replaced by $\exists x, \text{Constructible}(x)\land\phi$. Because the constructible universe is an inner model, this syntactic transformation produces a valid formal proof, that respects inference rules.

And the invocations of the axiom of choice become
$$\forall x, \text{Constructible}(x)\Rightarrow \exists f, \text{Constructible}(f)\land \text{ChoiceFunction}(f,x)$$

But that is no longer an axiom, it is a theorem of ZF. Therefore we have a formal proof of a contradiction in ZF. Is this correct?

I am wondering how far we can continue these equi-consistency proofs in ZF. Can we remove the axiom of foundation ? Even the axiom of infinity ? I doubt it because, if we could remove all axioms, ZFC would be equi-consistent with the empty theory, which is consistent.

Comment: You can remove foundation by the same trick. Now you would restrict your quantifiers to the well-founded universe. You cannot remove infinity, or you would end up with a theory that is essentially just Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: However, your phrasing is a bit strange. You can remove infinitely many instances of replacement, in several ways, and even ensure that no common subtheory suffices.  It is not clear to me that one is weaker than the other in any reasonable sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the axiom of foundations by the same argument: move from a universe of $\sf ZF-Fnd$ to the von Neumann universe, which is the largest well-founded and transitive class.

When you remove Infinity, Power set, or Replacement, you get strictly weaker theories. To see why, note that $V_\omega,\mathrm{HC}$ and $V_{\omega+\omega}$ are models of $\sf ZF-Infinity, ZF-Power, ZF-Replacement$ respectively. Therefore $\sf ZF$ proves these theories have a model, so they are consistent. In particular by Gödel's theorem none of them can prove that $\sf ZF$ itself is consistent.